# Kotlin Coroutine: get List of (T) from Flow<sealed class <list of <T>>>

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have the following function that return Flow<sealed class <list of < T > > > ,

`fun getItems() : Flow<Resources<List<Item>?>>`

How can I get list of Item from this function?

where Resources class as fllow:

```
 sealed class Resources<out T>(val data: T?) {
    class Success<T>(data: T) : Resources<T>(data)
    class Error(val throwable: Throwable) : Resources<Nothing>(null)
    object Loading : Resources<Nothing>(null)

    
    override fun toString(): String {
        return when (this) {
            is Success -> "Success: $data"
            is Error -> "Error: ${throwable.message}"
            is Loading -> "Loading"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `Resources` look like?

Comment: @ArpitShukla, I'm updated my question

Comment: What do you want in case the response is not `Success`?

Comment: I have a binding adapter which showing when loading or error

Comment: But you are trying to get a list out of Flow, do you want a null value if response is not `Success`?

Comment: did you mean this is a wrong way of implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```kotlin
val items: List<Item>? = getItems().first { it is Resources.Success }.data
```

It will pick the first `Success` emission from flow.
Note that `first` is a `suspend` function so you can call it from a coroutine only.